# Generic Type constraints on KeyValue practice not comparable

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

Ok, so i implemented a KeyValue program, essentially a manual Dictionary and now i am trying to make it generic. I am running into one problem with my if statement, and understand i need to define a type constraint, but can not figure out how to properly do that since my KeyValue store is of 2 types.

```cs
 class Generic_Key_Value
    {
        public struct KeyValueGeneric<T>
        {
            public readonly T Key;
            public readonly T Value;

            public KeyValueGeneric(T x, T y) 
            {
                Key = x;
                Value = y;
            }

        }
        public class MyDictionaryGenerics <T> 

        {
            public KeyValueGeneric<T>[] keyArray = new KeyValueGeneric<T>[20]; 

            public int Counter = 0;
            public bool matchFound = false;

            public T this[ T key]
            {
                set
                {
                    bool matchFound = false;
                    for (int i = 0; i < Counter; i++)
                    {

                        if (keyArray[i].Key == key) 
                        {
                            keyArray[i] = new KeyValueGeneric<T>(key, value);
                            matchFound = true;
                        }


                    }
                    if (matchFound == false)
                    {
                        keyArray[Counter] = new KeyValueGeneric<T>(key, value);
                        Counter++;
                    }

                }
                get
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < keyArray.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (key == keyArray[i].Key)
                        {

                            return keyArray[i].Value;


                        }

                    }

                    throw new KeyNotFoundException();


                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I can not compare

```cs
if (keyArray[i].Key == key) //THIS IS STATED AS NOT COMPARABLE
          {
              keyArray[i] = new KeyValueGeneric<T>(key, value);
              matchFound = true;
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two  generic type parameters, because probably you want to be able to have key types and value type to be different.

```
public struct KeyValueGeneric<TKey, TValue>
{
    public readonly TKey Key;
    public readonly TValue Value;

    public KeyValueGeneric(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

A good choice is to use the default `EqualityComparer<TKey>`:

```
if (EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default.Equals(keyArray[i].Key, key))
{
    keyArray[i] = new KeyValueGeneric<TKey, TValue>(key, value);
    matchFound = true;
}
```

As @madreflection pointed out, the EqualityComparer deals with values being `null` and avoids boxing of value types.

Comment: Why not use `EqualityComparer<T>`? You avoid NRE for reference types (assuming keys can be null in the first place) and boxing of `key` for value-type keys?

Comment: For my implementation and experience, the ```.Equals``` function provided the easiest way to compare the types, and i changed my parameter types to two separate ones too thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `T` is a generic and it is of any type, in your case  if condition checks `keyArray[i].Key` i.e `Type` is equal to input type which is stored in `key` variable.

If this is the case then, you can use [`Type.Equal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.equals?view=netframework-4.8) method.

Like,

```
if (keyArray[i].Key.Equal(key))  //Use ".Equals()" instead of "=="
   {
       keyArray[i] = new KeyValueGeneric<T>(key, value);
       matchFound = true;
   }
```